# Is it possible to get a token and client_id from the API GITHUB in the client application, without a server?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oauth

I need to get information from the GitHub API, which is only available to authorized users.

My Angular application should work without the server part; only js, html, css.

Is possible to transfer username/password or a personal token to GitHub in order to get the data?

Comment: Usually you can't request info from other sources except the one that loaded the front end page. It's a security problem if you can. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Keloo, the SOP is not an issue here. The [oauth implicit flow](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2) works as follows: The application redirects the user to the service provider permission dialog and includes some requires url-parameters. If the user grants permission, the browser will be redirected back to the application and the url will contain an access_token url-paramter. This token will be used to authenticate calls to the REST API which are [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [implicit oauth flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) will return the access_token when the browser is redirected back to your application after the permission page was confirmed. [But GitHub does not support the implicit flow](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/).

Therefore it is not possible to receive an `access_token` directly when GitHub redirects the browser back to your application. GitHub will only include a temporary `code`.

You need to request an `access_token` by doing a POST-request to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token with the temporary `code`. But for this request to work, the client secrecy has to be included.

As you are not allowed to share the client secret, you may not make it available to your Angular application. Therefore you need a server.